# Distributed cache using JCS

Tags: distributed, jcs

I am developing an application to manage **cache consistence in distributed environment**.
I have a clustered weblogic environment in which there are multiple managed servers(possibly on different IPs).

A java application will be deployed in all managed servers. An application in managed server 1 can update the cache where it has to be reflected in cache of managed server 2.

I found JCS lateral cache is suitable for this. I am struggling configuring the ccf for this scenario.

```
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes.TcpServers=localhost:XXXX,localhost:YYYY
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes.TcpListenerPort=ZZZZZ
```

Can someone explain :

- How to create above two pieces of configuration?
- How can I know the ports to configure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to decode the topology of your app. You / systems team need to choose IPs and ports of your system

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/LateralTCPAuxCache.html

There are two types of configuration TCP and UDP.
TCP configuration requires IP address and port number in configuration file:

```
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP=org.apache.commons.jcs.auxiliary.lateral.socket.tcp.LateralTCPCacheFactory
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes=org.apache.commons.jcs.auxiliary.lateral.socket.tcp.TCPLateralCacheAttributes
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes.TcpServers=localhost:1111,localhost:1112jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes.TcpListenerPort=1110
jcs.auxiliary.LTCP.attributes.AllowGet=false
```

The above link has more description on the properties and how it works. 
I am going to use these configurations myself. Will let you know how it goes.

-Bini

Comment: ..did you get this to work..I am trying to achieve same ?